# Creating a responsive image row

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I have images for my navigation bar that I made in Photoshop. How would I create a black background and have them displayed in a vertical row down the left side during a resize? Once it resizes they drop into the white and are not seen. Also if you are using Chrome you will have to hit the top left logo to move the nav images up for some reason..this is the only browser this does this in. [enter link description here](http://rwarner10.mydevryportfolio.com/CIS363B/project/index.html)

css:

```
/*---Navigation---*/
nav{
   float: right;
   margin-top: 12px;
   margin-right: 25px;

}
nav a: {
   padding: 15px;
}
#contact{
   padding: 4px;
}
#bio{
   padding: 4px;
}
#photography{
   padding: 4px;
}
#design{
   padding: 4px;
}
#sketches{
   padding: 4px;
}
#web{
   padding: 4px;
}
```

html:

```
<header>
    <a href="index.html" id="homeLogo" title="home"><img src="images/paintLogo.jpg" alt="Ryan Warner Eyemusic"></a>
   <nav>
    <a href="contact.html" id="contact"><img src="images/links/contact.png" 
       onmouseover="this.src='images/links/contactHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/links/contact.png'"></a>
    <a href="bio.html" id="bio"><img src="images/links/bio.png"
       onmouseover="this.src='images/links/bioHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/links/bio.png'"></a>
    <a href="photography.html" id="photography"><img src="images/links/photography.png"
       onmouseover="this.src='images/links/photographyHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/links/photography.png'"></a>
    <a href="design.html" id="design"><img src="images/links/design.png"
       onmouseover="this.src='images/links/designHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/links/design.png'"></a>
    <a href="sketches.html" id="sketches"><img src="images/links/sketches.png"
       onmouseover="this.src='images/links/sketchesHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/links/sketches.png'"></a>
    <a href="web.html" id="web"><img src="images/links/web.png"
       onmouseover="this.src='images/links/webHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/links/web.png'"></a>
   </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: What do you mean "during the resize"? Can you perhaps show some sample picture of what you want? When someone resizes the browser? Oh and vertical row = a column :). And nice grunge design

Comment: When the page comes up full screen you are able to see the nav images. However when you start to resize your browser down the nav images fall into the white and are unreadable. Thanks!

Comment: Ok maybe something like this http://www.starbucks.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting it on a small button on the side like the starbucks page is another story, but I'll help you out with your original request.

1. Set the logo to `float: left;`
2. Remove the height from your `header` (it prohibits it from expanding)
3. Set `overflow: auto;` on your `header` & `overflow: hidden;` on your `nav` to clear the floats. (You may also use the `clearfix` method but this one's easier).

Now your links will stay in the black when resizing. If you want it to become an openable button when smaller than, say 480px, you'll have to use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Notes:

- I noticed you set `mouseover` & `mouseout` on your links to toggle the image. However, it's more efficient to use the CSS `:hover` selector, eg. `nav a:hover { background-image: url(...)`
- Your images flicker a bit on loading, consider using a [CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) to avoid multiple requests.
- Lastly, if you use images for your navigation, be aware that it is no good for SEO, and provide at least a link `title` attribute.

Comment: sweet Thanks. That is exactly what I want. You don't by chance know how to get rid of the blue borders around the nav images in Internet Explorer? I used the border-style: none; but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce that on IE 11, I suppose it's the browser's default styling for links though, so try `nav a { text-decoraction: none; }`. Does that work?

Comment: No, nothing changes at all.

Comment: Do I put the title of the page in the title element or the title of the website?

Comment: Ah I found the problem: set `border: none` on `nav img`. And to your other question: the title can be in both, but that's not the kind of questions Stackoverflow is for, though.

Comment: However if I put that into the html document it does remove the borders..strange that the css code wasn't doing the trick.